# How to edit registration form fields?

Tags: form, field, registration

I want to edit the registration form on my site. I have set up new fields and added it to the field layout under setting. However, the changes still don't appear on the registration form. Another problem is that the registration form is not an entry. Under the menu bar, the registration form seems to be just an added URL. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

After adding the new fields to your field layout, you still need to update your template to display the new fields.  You can read the [templating docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/) on the Craft website to see how to output the individual fields.